Is docker daemon process shown in htop represents the daemon itself
I look at this screenshot:

Am I correct to assume that the CPU consumption that is showed by /usr/bin/dockerd is applicable to the docker daemon itself, not the processes that run inside the containers managed by the docker? For example, the /usr/bin/clickhouse-server process runs inside the container, but it's shown as a separate entry in the table.

Yes, your assumption is correct.
The entries for /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock represent different threads or child processes of the Docker daemon. Even though the ClickHouse server is running inside a container, its processes appear as separate entries because containers run as isolated processes on the host kernel.
